# Wild berries in Southern California

Tags: food, california

Are there any edible wild berries in southern California? Are there any conventional berries (like wild strawberries or blueberries) and how far out of the city do I have to go to find them?

Answer (score 5):

You can find wild berries growing in vacant lots and along roadsides even in the city— although I wouldn't venture to eat them, as they will have absorbed various toxins from traffic or polluted soil.

You'll find blackberry family bushes (dewberries, thimbleberries) in moist areas along the coast or along stream beds. In the mountains you will find gooseberries and wild currants. They also taught us in the Scouts that wild grapes and wild strawberries were to be found, but I've never come across any; you may have to go literally off the beaten path to find them.

Comment: Wild strawberries are quite common in the mountains of San-Diego county. The deer love them too, so you have to be diligent!

Answer (score 0):

We have a home on the back side of crestline in cedar pines park. On the downward slope of devil's canyon Towards silverwood Lake,there is a stream that runs past the home and we have found, Wild strawberries, wild currants, gooseberry, Blackberries, Elderflower and a heck of a lot of red raspberries.